# Setting up ADT fields in code

Tags: delphi, tclientdataset

I'm experimenting with a simple ClientDataSet project that uses a TADTField named Address which contains two subfields, Line1 and City, both of which are strings, size 20.  THe CDS is connected to a DBGrid and DBNavigator.

If I set up the CDS using TFieldDefs in the Object Inspector and the ChildDefs property of the ADT field, the project compiles and executes fine.

However, if I try to set up the ATD field and its children in code, I get two problems:

- Unlike when I use the FieldDefs method, the ATD "cell" doesn't appear in the DBGrid, so the Line1 and City sub-fields dont display inside it.  Instead they appear as ordinary fields and they are duplicated.  There is one "Line1" column, then a "City" one, then another "Line1" ...
- When I close the form, I get a "double-free" AV inside a second (?) call to TFields.Destroy.

Obvioulsly I'm doing something wrong but I can't see what it is.

Here's my code :

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  ADTField : TADTField;
  Field : TField;
begin
  // at this point, the clientDataSet has no TFields or TFieldDefs 
  Field := TIntegerField.Create(nil);
  Field.FieldName := 'ID';
  Field.DataSet := ClientDataset1;

  ADTField := TADTField.Create(nil);
  ADTField.FieldName := 'Address';
  ADTField.DataSet := ClientDataset1;

  Field := TStringField.Create(nil);
  Field.FieldName := 'Line1';
  Field.Size := 20;
  Field.DataSet := ClientDataset1;
  ADTField.Fields.Add(Field);

  Field := TStringField.Create(nil);
  Field.FieldName := 'City';
  Field.Size := 20;
  Field.DataSet := ClientDataset1;
  ADTField.Fields.Add(Field);

  ClientDataset1.CreateDataSet;
  ClientDataset1.Insert;
  ClientDataset1.FieldByName('ID').AsInteger := 1;
  try
    ADTField.Fields.FieldByName('Line1').AsString := '1, Railway Cuttings';
    ADTField.Fields.FieldByName('City').AsString := 'London';
  except
  end;
  ClientDataset1.Post;
end;
```

That's the entire code of the project.  I'm using D7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I remember being foxed by something similar when I first tried out ADT fields:  although the TFieldDefs editor in the IDE has an obvious way to add child FieldDefs to an TADTField, there's no counterpart in the IDE's TFields editor.

Anyway, I think you're not quite "parenting" the two fields that you want to be children of the ADT one correctly.  Instead of calling `ADTField.Fields.Add`, you need to do it via the field itself, by setting its `ParentField` property:

```
  Field := TStringField.Create(ClientDataset1);
  Field.FieldName := 'Line1';
  Field.Size := 20;
  Field.DataSet := ClientDataset1;
//  ADTField.Fields.Add(Field);
  Field.ParentField := ADTField;
```

And that btw is how you would do it in the IDE if you were setting up TFields instead of TFieldDefs.  You'd create your `Line1` and `City` fields in the ordinary way using the TFields editor, then select them in turn on the OI and set their `ParentField` property.  I think you'll find that they and the `Address` field will then display in your grid correctly and the AV on shutdown will go away.